# Tkinter is not showing string Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to display a popup message in tkinter but I don't know why it's not showing in the window. Here is my code :

```
def popupmsg(msg):
    popup = tk.Tk()
    popup.wm_title("Results ")

    data_string = tk.StringVar()
    data_string.set(msg)
    ent = tk.Entry(popup, textvariable=data_string, fg="black", bg="white", bd=0, state="readonly")
    ent.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    B1 = tk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command=popup.destroy)
    B1.pack()
    popup.mainloop()
```

This is how I am calling :

```
string = " "
for f in final:
    string = string + " " + f + " \n"
# print("Results : \n" + string)
popupmsg("Results : \n" + string)
```

This is I what  I get :
Msg is missing
[image]

Comment: The code is working for me.What error are you getting?

Comment: It does not show "msg"

Comment: @Gnanavel can you please read the question again, I have updated code .

Comment: It's a list that contains URLs .. even if I try `popupmsg("abc")` it does not show up there

Comment: @Gnanavel not at all , I don't know what is the issue

Comment: Use `toplevel()` instead of `Tk()`.  I think you have another instance of `Tk()` already, the root window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using more than one instance of `Tk()`. So the `StringVar()` doesnt know which parent to belong to, so to fix this, try replacing all child `Tk()` with `Toplevel()` leaving you with just one `Tk()`.

The non recommended way would be to say `data_string = tk.StringVar(master=popup)` but still creating two instance of `Tk()` is gonna cause another bunch of problems on the way. [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged#:%7E:text=From%20a%20technical%20standpoint%2C%20there%27s,hard%20for%20beginners%20to%20grasp.)

Since your not getting the output only and no error is shown, this would be the obvious error, if this does not work, please provide more debugging details or some more code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
import tkinter as tk
def popupmsg(msg):
    popup = tk.Tk()
    popup.wm_title("Results ")
    data_string = tk.StringVar()
    data_string.set(msg)
    ent = tk.Entry(popup, textvariable=data_string, fg="black", bg="white", bd=0)
    ent.configure(state='readonly')
    ent.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    B1 = tk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command=popup.destroy)
    B1.pack()
    popup.mainloop()
```

Comment: This code runs separately , but when I am replacing it within main file it's not showing Entry

Comment: So please put the full code inside main file in question.

Comment: If I remove `state="readonly` it displays an empty Entry widget but does not show any textvariable. If I try to print `data_string.get()` it prints the value of msg but it does not show up there

Comment: @HamzaArshad I updated my answer.Try that whether it works or not.